# Select2 box, load comma deliminated string

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a comma deliminated string say "Apple, Banana, Orange" and I want to pre-load a jquery select2 multi select box with these values so the user can remove some or all of them. How would I do this in my "get" method for the string?

Request to include code (C#):

```
string fruits = "Apple, Banana, Orange";

string _fruit;

public string Fruit
{
public string IncludedGroups
{
   get
   {
       if (_fruit != string.Empty)
       {
       //what to do here? how to break up string and return so select2 will recognize it as individual items
       }
      return null;
   }
   set { _fruit = value; }
   }
}
```

Comment: please include your codes.

Comment: which format does jquery expect?

Comment: @reshad code added.

Comment: @Aleksv it's select 2 so I need to load each individual string into it. A single one works perfect. Multiple ones are giving me the trouble. Thank you both for such fast replies :)

Comment: @Mujeebu Rahman thank you very much, but when I reach the javascript, the data has already been bound. I need to break up the string on the c# side somehow.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>
    <link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>


     $( document ).ready(function() {
         var mystr = 'Apple, Banana, Orange';
                 var results = mystr.split(",");
                 $.each(results, function (i, result) {
                     $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
                         value: result,
                         text: result
                     }));
                 });

      $("#mySelect").select2();

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/196/)

You can add it easily. You need to pass the array on pageload:
as follows:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#multipleSelectExample").select2();
             $("#multipleSelectExample").select2("val", [1,2,3]);
    }
);

            <option value="1">Apple</option>
            <option value="2">Banana</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Grapes</option>
            <option value="5">jackfriut</option>
```

Where array values are from option values.